# Can't ping other vlan on same stack switch

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, cisco-ios

I have to setup a stack of 3 Cisco 3850 switchs.  They are licences to IP Base feature.

I inspirated my setup from an another configuration we got here but those switches have the IP Services IOS. As my topic said, I'm unable to ping other vlan in the switch.

There's the scenario :

My stack will connect to a Cisco Switch that we don't manage. This switch provide us (via VPN MPLS) network we can use.

This switch (from ISP) have two ports (network) enable :

```
Port 1 L3 : 10.140.68.1/22
Port 2 L3 : 192.168.69.33/27
```

My switch stack (LAN) configuration looks like this :

```
ip routing

interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown

interface Vlan68
 ip address 10.140.68.2 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.140.68.4

interface Vlan69
 ip address 10.140.69.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.140.68.4

interface Vlan70
 ip address 10.140.70.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.140.68.4
 shutdown

interface Vlan71
 ip address 10.140.71.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.140.68.4
 shutdown

interface Vlan192
 ip address 192.168.69.33 255.255.255.224

router eigrp 100
 network 10.140.68.0 0.0.3.255
 network 192.168.69.32 0.0.0.31
 redistribute static
 passive-interface default
 eigrp stub connected summary

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.140.68.1

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description To MPLS SWITCH PORT 1
 switchport access vlan 68
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description To MPLS SWITCH PORT 2
 switchport access vlan 192
```

Someone can help me to configure the InterVlan routing and the I'm not sure if the 2 ports who'll be connected to the uplink switch is correct too.

I made ping test having a two laptops connected to the switch, 1 in vlan 68 and 1 in vlan 69.

**EDIT:** (for a comment below that I can't format)

```
Interface   IP-Address    OK?   Method  Status                  Protocol
Vlan1       172.16.100.1  YES   manual  administratively down   down
Vlan68      10.140.68.3   YES   manual  up                      up
Vlan69      10.140.69.1   YES   manual  up                      up
Vlan70      10.140.70.1   YES   NVRAM   administratively down   down
Vlan71      10.140.71.1   YES   NVRAM   administratively down   down
Vlan192     192.168.69.34 YES   manual  up                      up
```

**EDIT2:**
Now I can ping all vlan from the switch (via the console connection). I can put a laptop in a port in the `Vlan68` and ping the switch (by all vlan ip address) same thing from a laptop in the `Vlan192`. BUT, if I put a laptop in a port of Vlan69 I can't ping the switch from any vlan IP even the `Vlan69` (69.1). When I do a `show arp` the laptop's mac and IP address don't show. I try with many laptop and samething everytime.

**Resolution**
The problem came of the fact that some interface configuration about dhcp snooping and arp inspection prevents statics address ip. Adding a DHCP solve the problem.

Comment: You say port 1 (presumably the device connected to port 1) is 10.140.68.1/*22* but the vlan 68 interface is config'd for /24.  Is that /22 a typo?

Comment: @dk1, it's not a typo. The device it's place as a kind of edge mark that "propagate" those two networks at our site. So our site can use the 10.140.68.1/22 network for users/servers and the other for video conferencing.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the network mask... if the ISP will not perform local network routing for you (with correct vlan tags), then you need to use the correct subnet mask on a single vlan interface.

Comment: Nowhere in your original question do you even begin to hint at having DHCP snooping or DAI configured.  Naturally you will have problems with using statically configured IP addresses on a network configured to use DAI.  Next time consider posting your full configuration rather than just what you think is important, and the community may be able to help with a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came of the fact that some interface configuration about dhcp snooping and arp inspection prevents static address ip. Adding a DHCP solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In general, a VLAN SVI will not be "UP" if there are no ports within that VLAN that are up. As only 2 of your VLANs are assigned to interfaces (as per the limited bit of config provided), only 2 VLANs should be operational.

Comment: Best way to rectify no `UP` ports is to plug in a trunk link, ethernet loop, or patch an access VLAN into a different access VLAN.

Comment: I got two laptops connected on the stack, 1 in vlan 68 and 1 in vlan 69.